# Is there a group/organization/network of people who create TeX/LaTeX-based versions of old or public domain texts?

Tags: typography, books, publishing

Simply put, is there a Project Gutenberg for TeX and Friends?

Comment: This is a good question but I fear it does not belong to this site?

Comment: It might not be the best fit for the site, but where else am I going to find an answer?

Comment: Is http://www.pmonta.com/etext/ the kind of thing you’re looking for?

Comment: @Thérèse: Nice to know!

Comment: in fact, mathematic books on Project Guttenberg are processed with LaTeX: http://dw2.tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-1/tb100hwang.pdf http://www.pgdp.net/wiki/Category:LaTeX

Comment: @Thérèse If you add your comment as an answer, I'll mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don’t know whether this is a group or a solo effort, but there are resources for typesetting Project Gutenberg books at [www.pmonta.com/etext/](http://www.pmonta.com/etext/), which links to the resources at [www.sandroid.org/GutenMark/](http://www.sandroid.org/GutenMark/). And, as michal-h21 commented, Project Gutenberg itself often presents mathematical and scientific works as LaTeX files with the PDF output (e.g., [Euclid](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/21076)).