# Which Class and Packages for typesetting War and Peace ( a novel narrative)

Tags: book-design, learning, tutorials

Project: format ["War and Peace"](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2600) on 8.5" X 5.5" double sided pages, using open source software, with a pdf submittal.  The utf8 text is freely available to anyone, and no one can own sole publication rights, since that work falls into the public domain.  The goal is take as few hours as possible, while making it look as good as possible. The pdf would include everything except the front and back cover of the book, all the inner pages in other words.   (War and Peace is actually a Book of "books" rather than "parts" each with many chapters).

So, what manuals for compiler, class and other packages would be best to read up on, or would you skip LaTeX and use another open source tool?  Images, Colors and Scientific Formula etc., are not allowed in the finished product.

### Edit:

I've read a few introductions to LaTeX and can quickly compile long books.   War and Peace has a lot of narrative, and it's very quick to markup with LaTeX then compile into a pdf book.  But the result isn't what I'm looking for when I try to use a minimal amount of introductory LaTeX.

The basic question at the top revolves around what classes, packages and/or compilers could be used.  There will probably only be a few short answers, so I disagree with placing this question on hold.  More folks than formatters of academic and scientific documents should be empowered to effectively use the full capability of LaTeX.

I've read lots of comments, but zero solutions.  see below.  Why?  I feel that this question was marked on hold because it wasn't fielded for an academic or scientific work, and folks are certainly acting like I'm asking for their programming trade secretes.

Comment: I think I should probably take this to another forum correct?  Since this is open discussion?

Comment: I am a bit confused. Is that a real question?

Comment: What do you mean by "real" question?  Yes, I think it may be too general of one on StackExchange, but if it isn't...

Comment: Read an introduction to LaTeX and all of the question can be answered. It is just text.

Comment: I've already read an introduction.  LaTeX looks like a textbook.  I want it to look like War and Peace.  Is there a fix?

Comment: That comment doesn't make any sense. LaTeX is a language and a language cannot look like a textbook. *War and Peace* is a piece of literature. How can you make something look like a piece of literature? What is there to fix?

Comment: I understand it's a language.  That's why I've asked the question "what manuals for compiler, class and other packages would be best to read up on, or would you skip LaTeX and use another open source tool?" so that War and Peace wouldn't get compiled into a manual like book.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  Not sure how you’re measuring the time we take or awarding grades, but you could take a look at the resources in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168756

Comment: I assure you this has not been put on hold because of the content of the work you are typesetting.

Comment: Therese, the word "imagine" is implied.  I didn't realize any stackexchange user would actually think they would be rewarded, beyond up votes etc.

Comment: @Thérèse There were an awful lot of comments to this question, but your tidbit has been the only one so far that pointed to possible solutions.

Comment: I think that the reason this question was put on hold, and certainly the reason why I voted not to reopen, is that the question is too broad. Any answers would be opinion based.

Comment: I believe if folks would quit commenting and start offering solutions this would go quicker

Comment: Phrases like "the result isn't what I'm looking for" is presumably why this question is considered too broad and too vague. There is not -- as everyone knows -- only one way to typeset a novel or one 'way' that a novel looks. So what kind of advice do you expect to get?  This seems like this question is composed of several (perhaps dozens) or smaller, discrete questions that would be perfectly suitable for this site --- about things like fonts, margins, headers, sectional divisions, TOCs, etc. (And, I'd bet many of them already exist here and have perfectly good answers.)

Comment: Note also that questions like 'is it better to typeset a novel in single-spaced lines or use `setspace`'s `\onehalfspacing`?' will likely be closed as primarily opinion-based. This site is (in theory) oriented to questions of a TeXnical nature, not about whether an X-style or Y-style is nicer.

Comment: My question isn't which is "nicer" but rather which would produce a TeXnically correct pdf for War and Peace.  If I would have put X Thesis, or for Y Chemistry Department, it wouldn't have been held up, I believe.

Comment: Now what is a 'correct pdf'? And how does that relate to 'the result isn't what I'm looking for'? And if someone gave you 'the answer' for how to produce a 'correct pdf' for a thesis, how would that answer be different from what you need for this question?

Comment: one that any reasonable person would say, "this pdf would pass for War and Peace"   It's fairly objective to say, this pdf is a manual, or this pdf is a narrative.  It only gets subjective if you try to assign grades like, C- or A+ etc.  I'm not going that far.  I'm simply asking for the necessary LaTeX programming to make it look like a novel.  How simple is that?

Comment: I've already explained that your question should be broken up into the actual discrete questions. Also: it is clear that it could 'pass for War and Peace' in many different ways: e.g. [1](https://books.google.ca/books?id=N1MEAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=war+and+peace&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), [2](https://books.google.ca/books?id=LB-OLxQWzPcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=war+and+peace&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), [3](https://books.google.ca/books?id=no6iEu4lWEgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=war+and+peace&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), etc.

Comment: I concur that your question is so broad that I actually recommend you to forget about Latex at all and go straight for plain pdftex. that's what I do when I typeset my project gutenberg e-books. who needs latex anyway :-)

Comment: Go here for over 30 book templates for use in LaTeX. https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/book#.WAbo7CQjpiN

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but since your question is on hold, and it certainly does not fit the format for this site, I cannot answer it here. If you put your question on good old comp.text.tex, which does not follow the rules of this site, I may share my simple plain tex solution.

Comment: okay, I will look into those solutions

Comment: There is 'push back' here because as it stands this is a vague and opinion-based question. You'd see the same for a thesis in mathematics _except_ normally there will be some university rules we can eventually tease out: they tend to be objective if not particularly aesthetically-pleasing. Here, beyond `\documentclass{book}\begin{document} <text here>\end{document}` there really is nothing concrete to say: please break down specific technical problems into separate questions and ask them.

Comment: @erreka The most active answer to that question is by the OP of this question.

Comment: @Johannes_B That's part of my point `:o)` Anyway, I just added my own answer to that question.

Comment: After reading some of your questions and answers: You are looking for `pandoc`. Direct LaTeX is obviously not what you are looking for.

Comment: (La)TeX was designed for professional mathematical typesetting on top of the usual professional typesetting. If you don't need math, don't use it. If you need simple chapter headings, define them simple.

Comment: @erreka -- (I realize I'm saying this to a 'plain' user, but) the `minimal` class may be too minimal for book-production purposes. It was/is meant for testing purposes, if i recall.

Answer (score 0):

### Compiler

Just use PdfTeX:  It's simplest and gives the best results.

### Class

Use scrbook:  It's a KOMA-Script class that has a super detailed manual.  It has many more features and options than the other classes.

### Packages

```
\usepackage[options]{geometry}
```

You will need to add your unusual book dimension into the geometry options.

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Choose a T1 type font for superior quality.  Go to the [LaTeX Font Catalog](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) to find your favorite.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Use Unicode rather than ascii.  Fiction has lots of dialog.  It's better to use right and left quotation marks (Unicode) than the non-directional keyboard quotes (ascii) in a Novel.

```
\usepackage{microtype}
```

This adds microtypography for quality formatting improvements.

```
\usepackage{setspace} \onehalfspacing
```

A novel is better typeset in one and onehalfspacing so the text doesn't get crammed together too much.  That makes for more enjoyable reading.

```
\usepackage{hyphenat}%
          \hyphenation{word-list,%
                       hy-phen,%
                       my-word,%
                       neverhypen,%
                       excitatory%
                       }
```

There will probably be words you want to add to the LaTeX hyphenate/don't hyphenate dictionary.

```
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
```

You will want to customize page headers, footers and more.

Also, check out these TeX examples from [Project Gutenberg](http://www.pmonta.com/etext/), where other novel classics have been formatted using LaTeX.

Comment: `pdfTeX` uses the PlainTeX format: is this really what you recommend? Or did you mean to recommend using `pdfLaTeX`? (By the way, I'm not the downvoter.)

Comment: I thought that people commonly use the term "pdfTeX" to refer to pdfLaTeX all the time, and the same for XeTeX and LuaTeX.  (You know you can edit and improve the answer if you find it to be in error, don't you?)  BTW, I believe the tags pdfTeX, XeTeX and LuaTeX are more popular than pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: The compiler `pdftex` will use the pdfTeX engine with the format `plain`. The compiler `pdflatex` will use the same engine with the format `latex`. Why do you recommend a KOMA class and then suggest using `geometry`? If you are really typesetting the original work, `T1` is a quite unsuitable encoding.

Comment: Because the KOMA-Script manual suggests [in section 2.6] to use package Geometry rather than it's own internal Typearea feature, in cases that require predefined margins.  And since 8.5" X 5.5" is not a standard paper size, I figured Geometry would work better.  Typearea works great for larger pages with generous margins.  But I wanted a bit larger and specifically customized area.  cfr, do you have any solutions or more questions?

Comment: I'm disappointed that so few folks are offering any solutions whatsoever

Comment: Because the question is: *Can somebody help me build a motor vehicle that looks like a car?* An answer to that questioin will be used and needs to be awareded, by more than rep.

Comment: There are professional typesetting services available.

Comment: That wasn't my question.  I'm looking for solutions to it, not your advertising.

Comment: In this case, LaTeX is an overkill. On Plain simply set the font, paper and box dimensions and let the page and line breaking algorithms do their job.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a kind of wiki entry for other users? You (OP) have answered more than one questions concerning that topic. That would explain the broad question.

Comment: If a moderator reads this: Can you send me a private message via e-mail (if you can obtain it)? Reason: I have been working on a new document class specifically for novel writers, not math. I have actually used it for real work (in early stage) for a commercially printed book.  I believe I am close to final stage and class documentation. Includes re-worked pdfx, too. Hopefully a moderator can nag me about it, and advise what do to with it when it is finished.

Comment: I hope that class makes it to CTAN and TeX-Live full distributions.  It sounds like a really simple solution to what I'm facing.

Comment: @user12711 I fear you'll find that the developer's defaults may not fit your needs/taste after all.

Comment: @erreka I'm not too picky; just looking for something quick, basic and literary, like the Book class, but without the obvious technical numbering.  (I don't want to have to spend hours programming a preamble and googling for packages to do this or that) I like the Project-Gutenberg pdfs I've looked at today, and looking at their templates now.  Someone sent the link yesterday.  Also, I'll make a post latter on the TeX forum  (I think) you sent a link to.

Comment: @user12711 perhaps you should look at my answer to the referenced question on top of this page.

Comment: I'm looking at that now.  There's a lot of great new answers just posted there.