# Where can I put my LaTeX skills to good use?

Tags: typography

I really hope such a non-technical question is allowed here...
I have recently finished big parts of my studies and as such I have been relaxing for a while. After reading [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends) thread I am now inspired to make a beautiful document of my own. The only problem is that I Don't really have anything to type.

This already leads to my question: Where could one use typesetting to contribute something somewhat meaningful? I have thought of things like transcribing articles for Wikimedia Commons or something similar. Any input is welcome!

And if such "soft-questions" are not allowed I'll of course delete this!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: You can modify the listings  package to be Unicode compliant. This will be a great contribution to the community. My estimate it needs 6-weeks development work.

Comment: You can get a maths book from archive.org (search for Euler) and typeset it for https://www.gutenberg.org/  they accept .tex formats

Comment: Designing and implementing templates / document classes that imitates some publishers' book style, writing tests for those widely used packages like tikz and siunitx, and maybe writing latex guides.

Comment: The top of all texts is Bible. Sources are here: https://www.crosswire.org/sword/

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168721

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent question. Keep looking at this site and the questions asked and see what you can answer. That is always a good way of using your talents. Or are you trying to think of something more generic like a package to solve a range of problems or a class for a very different kind of document? See @Thérèse comment.

Comment: If you do not have anything to type, the package `lipsum` is ideal to fill a lot of pages with LaTeX without anything to say. Or if you don't trust that Lore Ipsum is really are meaningless, take the speech of any politician in election campaign. Nothing better to put word after word without saying anything at all.

Comment: Probably someone in the Community will compile all comments into a nice answer. As a non English native, I really advocate for non English LaTeX material for spreading the word ... I mean spreading LaTeX.

Comment: If you are a non-native English speaker, you can translate https://www.learnlatex.org/ in your language.